# bootsrap php contact form value shows error <br /><b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: myThema in <b>C:\x\testForm.php</b> on line <b>105</b><br />

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I am using bootstrap and I want to create a contact Form. I have create a File with the name testForm.php and there I have written my php and my html code(should I make a different files? one for php and one for html?). My file starts with the php code to and after the html code. As soon as I put an `<?php echo....` in the html area, everywhere, appears all the time in the site Undefined index: .for example
[image]

Now I m trying only with one parameter :thema to see if it works and how it works and if I put something to value comes the result like the picture above.
My php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $thema = $_POST['thema'];



    // Check if thema has been entered
    if (!$_POST['thema']) {
        $errThema = 'Please enter your thema';
    }


}
```

?>

and my html code:

```
<!-- MAIN SEITE -->
<h4><p class="text-primary"><u>Neuanforderungsformular</u></p></h4>

<!-- START FORM -->
<form method="post" role="form" action="testForm.php">
<!-- Thema Feld -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="usr">Thema / Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="thema" name="thema" class="form-control input-lg" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['thema']); ?>">
</div>
<!-- Email Adresse Feld-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <div class="input-group col-sm-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ihre Email Addresse" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@teswt.de</span>
</div>
```

how can I fix the provbem so my contact form will works?

Comment: You declaring `$thema` first before checking if it has been set

Comment: How can I checked if it has been set?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['someName']))`

Comment: but I have isset at the begging

Comment: that's for the submit button, you should also check the other fields if they are set or not, especially if you are accepting blank values

Comment: I have put also an if(isset(!$_POST['thema)) and comes this Fatal error: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projekt\testForm.php on line 7

Comment: Change your `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['thema']); ?>`   to   `<?=if(isset($_POST['thema'])) ? $_POST['thema'] : ' ' ; ?>`

Comment: I did it and now comes Fatal Error.... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projektl\testForm.php on line 109

Comment: sorry, remove the `if` like this `<?=(isset($_POST['thema'])) ? $_POST['thema'] : ' ' ; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

use like this

```
$thema = isset($_POST['thema']) ? $_POST['thema'] : '';
```

instead of

```
$thema = $_POST['thema'];
```

update.1

try it

```
<?php $thema = !empty($thema) ? $thema : ''; ?>
<input type="text" id="thema" name="thema" class="form-control input-lg" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($thema); ?>">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" id="thema" name="thema" class="form-control input-lg" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['thema']); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (isset($_POST['thema'])){
        $thema = $_POST['thema'];
    } else {
        $thema = 'Please enter your thema';
    }
}
?>
```

You should check first if `$thema` has been set. What you did is you are using `$_POST['thema']` without checking, thus the error appearing in the text field

Comment: yes I have tryed and still doesnt do anything appears the same as is at the picture above and when I click submit doesnt change anything

Comment: I edited it, if I'm not mistaken, if `$thema` has not been set for whatever reason, `Please enter your item` will appear in the text field

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing to   $_POST['thema']) also when an entry for thema is not present in $_POST

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="usr">Thema / Title:</label>
<input type="text" id="thema" name="thema" class="form-control input-lg" 
        value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['thema']); ?>">
 </div>
```

then you should use a proper setting for a var eg $myThema

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      if (isset($_POST['thema'])){
          $myThema = $_POST['thema'];
      } else {
          $errThema = 'Please enter your thema';
          $myThema = '';
      }
  }
```

.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="usr">Thema / Title:</label>
<input type="text" id="thema" name="thema" class="form-control input-lg" 
        value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($myThema); ?>">
 </div>
```

Comment: I have also tryed still the same ...comes at the value instead of thema mythema

Comment: please update your question and add the exact error message ( with the lines number and a  note for show this code line)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like that:

```
function GetPostOrDefault($key, $default = '')
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_POST))
    {
        return $_POST[$key];
    }
    return $default;
}
```

And then

```
<input value="<?= GetPostOrDefault('thema') ?>">
```

or

```
<input value="<?= GetPostOrDefault('thema', 'Neues Thema') ?>">
```

You get this error because the index is not defined, if you have made no post.

That means `$_POST['thema']` is only available if you have submitted a form that contains a field with the name `thema`. On your initial page load, you do a GET request. The form is not submitted.

Comment: what do you mean the index is not defined?

Comment: Where should I put this code with the function inside the html area or in the php area? sorry I m new :(

Comment: On the place where you have all your Helper functions (PHP). If not create one, and make sure you `include` them before your HTML. @JavaMunich

Comment: be sure you have not others  reference to $_POST['thema'] or others array with an index  'thema'  because in my answer  this index  is used  ony if is set ..

Answer (score 1):

Simply move your default $thema value outside of the check for $_POST['submit']. Your current code only sets it when the form has been submitted.

```
$thema = '';
$errThema = '';

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // Check if thema has been entered
    if (!$_POST['thema']) {
        $errThema = 'Please enter your thema';
    } else {
        $thema = $_POST['thema'];
    }
}
```

Of course, you should then display `$thema` instead of `$_POST['thema']` in your form.